# Odoo- Hide website menu when no user is logged in and vice versa

Tags: xml, odoo, odoo-11, odoo-website

I am working on the menu of the Odoo website module, but I am stuck at hiding a specific menu when the user is logged out and if any user is logged in it should display.

I am writing a sample to display how I created the menu-

```
<odoo>
 <data noupdate="0">
   <record id="furdo_portal_sale_order_menu" model="website.menu">
     <field name="name">Sale Orders</field>
     <field name="url">/my/orders</field>
     <field name="sequence" type="int">1</field>
   </record>
 </data>
</odoo>
```

Here the problem I am facing is this menu of **Sale Order** is visible to even logged out users.
Can anyone help me out with the code on hiding for logged out user and visible to the logged in users?

> Everything should be code based.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Got my answer

```
<odoo>
  <data>
    <template id="custom_sign_in" customize_show="True" inherit_id="website.layout" name="Custom Sign In">
      <xpath expr="//ul[@id='top_menu']" position="replace">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav ml-auto text-right" id="top_menu">
          <li class="nav-item" t-if="website.user_id != user_id">
            <a class="nav-link" role="menuitem" t-attf-href="/my/orders">
              <span>Sale Order</span>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item divider"></li>
          <li class="nav-item dropdown" t-if="website.user_id != user_id">
            <a href="#" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
              <b>
                <span t-esc="user_id.name"/>
              </b>
            </a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu js_usermenu" role="menu">
              <a href="/my/home" role="menuitem" class="dropdown-item">My Account</a>
              <a id="o_logout" class="dropdown-item" role="menuitem" href="/web/session/logout?redirect=/">Logout</a>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item" t-if="website.user_id == user_id">
            <a class="nav-link" href="/web/login">
              <b>Sign in</b>
            </a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </xpath>
    </template>
  </data>
</odoo>
```